# Is it risky to export rabbitmq port in docker-compose?

Tags: security, rabbitmq, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

In the `docker-compose` file in the [hawkbit github project](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/blob/master/hawkbit-runtime/docker/docker-compose-monolith-mysql.yml), the `rabbitmq` service exports its port `15672` and `5672`. And the `hawkbit` service is accessing these ports using the hostname `rabbitmq` (so the internal docker network).

By exporting these ports, the `rabbitmq` service is now accessible from the outiside with the credientials `guest:guest` which does not seems really secure to me.

Therefore I was wondering why were these ports exported. Do they have another usage that I am not aware of ?

I already tried to remove the ports from the `docker-compose` file and restart the service, and all the basic functions of hawkbit seems to be working. So I would like the confirmation that this will not break my application in a way that I don't understand.